# Look for front-end effect

Tags: effect

Im looking for this effect in background  http://prism.umbrella.al/agency/. I saw it on few sites. This with green line and dots. Can you tell me how its called or give a link?

Answer (score 0):

It a canvas drawing, 
using mouse move event to fetch coordinates of mouse and draw accordingly

you can see there page source to check the code